# VB.Net Date.ParseExact Culture issue

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net and I create a list of months (3 char representation) by using the following function.

```
Public Function getMonths() As Array
    Dim months As String = ""
    For i = 1 To 12
        months += StrConv(MonthName(i, True), VbStrConv.ProperCase) + ","
    Next
    months = months.Substring(0, months.Length - 1)
    getMonths = months.Split(",")
End Function
```

This works beautifully, as the site I am building can change language etc on the fly.

However when I try to then change the month back to the numeric value to process using this function

```
Public Function monthToNumber(ByVal monthin As String, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Integer
    monthToNumber = DateTime.ParseExact("01/" + monthin + "/1999", "dd/MMM/yyyy", culture).Month
End Function
```

, the date.ParseExact throws an exception of date input is not in a valid string.

The month is being produce by the culturalisation, so I can't understand the failure.  This only happens with a culture of {pt-PT}.  The process works fine for spain, uk, france,italy.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `DateTime.ParseExact`, you have to use the right [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For `pt-PT`, it's not `/`, but `-`.

`/` can work as default `DateSeparator`, but only if you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. But if you do, you can't parse the culture specific date abbreviation.

That's why your code fails.

---

To generate the month abbreviations, simple use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviatedmonthnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames`](http://DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames); no need to write a method yourself.

Also, you should look into [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (another thing you don't have to reinvent).

For parsing the string back, you could use something like

```
monthToNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(monthin, "MMM", culture).Month
```

No need for day/year if you simply use `MMM` for your format string.